# How to efficiently merge PySpark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, merge, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes in Pyspark that have been merging for about two days. The first is about 6,000,000 features x 2600 rows and the second is about 30 features x 2600 rows. I suspect what is taking so long is the actual preparation in spark prior to the merge. Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split, create_map, lit
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import IndexToString, StringIndexer, VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

sql_c = SQLContext(sc)

df = sql_c.read.option("maxColumns", 10000000).option("header", "true").options(samplingRatio=0.01).option("inferSchema", "true").csv('join_rows_no_prepended_new_line.csv')

df2 = sql_c.read.option("maxColumns", 10000000).option("header", "true").options(samplingRatio=0.01).option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").csv('metadata_merged.txt')

#create a new column with a SampleID that matches the SampleID columns from the metadata df.
df = df.withColumn('#SampleID', split(df['# Gene Family'], '\_')[0])

df = df.drop("# Gene Family")
feature_cols = df.columns
df = df.join(df2, col("df.SampleID Gene Family")==col("df2.#SampleID"), how='inner')
```

The last line is the one running single-threaded for two days. Is there a better way to do this in Pyspark in terms of data preparation or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Spark SQL is definitely not the right tool for the job.

  Because Spark SQL uses relational model and query planner with optimizer, there is significant storage and computational overhead in terms of the number of columns. The lower bound is linear (the cost of representing schema), but in practice complexity of the query planner is much higher, and in the worst case scenario exponential.

  As a result Spark SQL can be used comfortably when the number of columns doesn't exceed few thousand, though it can be pushed if necessary into lower tens of thousands. Millions of columns is just no go.
- Inefficient plain text format is arguably not the right tool for the job.
- Spark ML is probably not the right tool for the job.

  In general reference Spark ML algorithms can operate reasonably well on wide *assembled* data, as long as the data is sparse. There is not enough information in question to determine if this the case or not.

  In some cases widish data can handled in Spark, but it requires lower level optimizations (smarter encoding, using lower precision numerics) than available in Spark ML.
- Spark in general might or might not be the right tool for the job.

  Built-in functions and commonly used packages assume that data you use is long and (relatively) narrow*, and won't work well, if at all, with very wide data. It is possible to address that with custom reader logic, and custom algorithms, but it is not something you'll get out-of-the-box, and depending on a problem, finding a scalable solution might prove challenging.

Some of these points can be easily addressed (for example falling back to RDD API to load, parse and assemble data should address optimizer bottleneck), other might require significant amount of work (ensemble models with subsets of features on short data can be efficiently trained in parallel, as long as one can ensure efficient selective access to the data). The question remains if it is really worth the effort - dimensions of data suggest somewhere in the range 100GB of data - nothing that can cannot be handled in memory on a mid-range server.

---

* That of course is not specific to Spark. Majority of distributed processing tools out there makes similar assumptions by default.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'm wondering as to what the correct tool for the job would be. I can write a raw text join that would be faster than this, but (as you picked up on) need a tool with which to run the ML. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of any tool that would be designed with such data in mind. If not any other reason, because wider than longer comes with severe statistical issues. it is not hard to suggest some solutions or workarounds in specific cases, but not in a general case.If "getting a bigger box" is not an option I'd really suggest preprocessing data, to achieve efficient direct access, and looking at ensembles with subsets of columns - you shouldn't even need distributed or particularly powerful system for that.